# Could not find name 'label'. Did you mean 'babel'?

Tags: reactjs, label, babeljs

I am using React and get this message when I hover over the label tag within this simple form element. I have never gotten it before with this project, and I have not installed babel to my package manager. Why am I getting this all of a sudden?

```
    <div className={styles["form-element"]}>
      <label className={styles['form-label']} htmlFor="assignee">priority</label>
      <select className={styles.priorities}>
        <option value="none" >
          None
        </option>
        <option value="low" >
          Low
        </option>
        <option value="medium" >
          Medium
        </option>
        <option value="high" >
          High
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: are you using .js file or .jsx?

Comment: I am using .jsx

Comment: can you update the `styles` also in your question?